# my library for arduino don't work. why?

Tags: arduino

This is my first attempt to build a library for arduino. This is just an example for me to understand how to transfer values to functions in librarys on arduino. But it does not work and I do not understand why.

TESTDUINO.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "TESTDUINO.h"

void TESTDUINO::TestPrint(string w, string h){
    Serial.println("TestPring#" + w + "#" + h);
}
```

TESTDUINO.h

```
#ifndef Test_h
#define Test_h

class TESTDUINO{
public:
    void TestPrint(string w, string h);
};

#endif
```

arduino file

```
#include <TESTDUINO.h>

TESTDUINO testduino;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 testduino.TestPrint("200","200");
}
```

I am a C# Programmer and not so familiar with the C language so I'm sure I made a beginner's mistake.

Comment: What error are your recieving? Or what result?
First, you need a constructor and declare a new instance....

Comment: error: 'string' has not been declared
void TestPrint(string w, string h); 
How do i do that? in c# I know but in c++/arduino I am new at this. I tried to set up an array of char[] but it does not work for me.

Comment: Try with `String`. See also : [link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject)

Comment: i get : error: 'String' has not been declared
  void TestPrint(String w, String h);

Comment: did you try putting `#include "Arduino.h"` in the h file instead of the cpp one? And of course use the capital S for `String`...
Anyway... This is just a test library, ok. But... I suggest you to avoid using complex types such as `String`.. Fixed sized buffers (e.g. `char mystring[10]`) are much better

Comment: its a test for String. So I have to use it.

Comment: you say c but you are using classes?  I guess you confused c++ with c ?

Comment: "does not work" is a meaningless sequence of words. The detailed description of the problem has to be present in the question.  Not in the comments under the question, but in the question itself. Provide it now.